# How to detect if ionic 6 application is running on iPad?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Trying to detect if the application is running on iPad does not work, `this.platform.is('iOS')` is returning `FALSE` on cordova iOS platform `ios 6.2.0`.

```
 platform.ready().then(() => {
            if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
                console.log("running on iOS device!");
            }});
```

This code used to work on previous cordova iOS platforms as expected!

My application uses ionic version `6.20.4` and `cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7` is installed

Please note that the code works %100 for detecting iPhone

Comment: have you tried `this.platform.is('ipad')`?

Comment: I did and it returns false for iPad both in actual device and on emulator.